# Как правильно построить запрос в PostgreSQL x Python?

Tags: python, postgresql

Очень нужна помощь!
Есть база данных.
В ней таблицы: users_data, table_interest_1, table_interest_2, table_interest_3, table_interest_4

В таблице users_data столбцы: user_id, interest_1, interest_2, interest_3, interest_4
В столбце user_id - айди юзера в телеграме

В столбцах interest_1, interest_2, interest_3, interest_4 содеражатся цифры.
Например, в interest_1 значение 2, interest_2 значение 0, interest_3 значение 7, interest_4 значение 3. Это значит что пользователь получил 2 сообщения по interest_1, 0 сообщений по interest_2 и так далее.

Надо 1:

- из таблицы table_interest_1 строку 3 и чтобы отправить ее юзеру.
- из таблицы table_interest_2 ничего не брать потому что значение в столбике interest_2 равно нулю
- из таблицы interest_3 строку 8 чтобы отправить ее юзерру..
  и так далее

Надо 2: Увеличить значение столбцов interest_1, interest_2, interest_3, interest_4 в таблице users_data на 1 для строки user_id

Я понимаю как это сделать обычными SQL запросами. Но это будет громоздко, особенно если в таблице users_data строк будут тысячи.
Читал бегло что в postgres можно строить связи между таблицами и формировать запрос, но пока не разобрался как это можно сделать.

Буду признателен, если дадите наводку.

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035) Пункты 5 и 3.